# Pandas to_csv writing extra " on column containing raw json

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I'm attempting to save my dataframe as csv after processing my data.

One caveat is I have a column containing the 'raw json' of the file as well.

When pandas saves the file using to_csv(header=False), I get the following

```
1,2,"{""col_1"":""1"",""col_2"":""1""}"
```

My dataframe looks like this:

| col_1 | col_2 | raw_json |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | {"col_1":1,"col_2":1} |

I've tried adding the json col something like:

```
for i, row in df:
    i_val = row.to_json()
    df.at[i,'raw_json'] = i_val
```

Expected csv:

```
1,2,{"col_1":"1","col_2":"1"}
```

Comment: The CSV format uses quotes to escape fields that themselves contain the separator, and two quotes to escape quotes in such fields. What you get is valid CSV, as can be verified by reading the file back using a CSV reader that knows how to handle the format (e.g.. `pd.read_csv`, or `csv.reader` or Excel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, sep=';')
```

As @pranav-hosangadi was explaining:

> "CSV format uses quotes to escape fields that themselves contain the
> separator"

So when you set `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` you disable that behavior and nothing will be quoted.

**Important:**
Note that the separator of the csv will be `";"` in this case, so you'll need to be sure that your fields not contains`";"` characters that could broke your csv